# How can I access an object of type A that's within an object of type B using pipes and mapping?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm brand new to Angular and am struggling to grab the info I need from my data.  I have a user object that has a MovieRating object as one of it's members.

```
import { IMovieRating } from "../Movies/movie-rating";

export interface IUser{
    userId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    gender: string;
    age: number;
    movieRatings: IMovieRating[];
}
```

And here is the IMovieRating interface

```
export interface IMovieRating {
    id: string;
    rating: number
}
```

One method I have in my User Service class is called GetUser, which returns an Observable<IUser | undefined>

```
getUser(userId: Number): Observable<IUser | undefined>{
  return this.getUsers()
  .pipe(map((users:IUser[]) => users.find(u=>u.userId == userId)))
}
```

I'm trying to write a method that gets the user ratings from the user object, but I haven't been able to get it right.  I've tried a few different ways, 2 are commented out, one is not.  Am I on the right track?

```
getUserRatings(userId: number): Observable<IMovieRating[]>{
  // return this.getUser(userId)
  // .pipe(map((user: IUser | undefined) => user?.movieRatings))
  
  let result =  this.getUser(userId)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => {
      data?.movieRatings
    })
  );

  // let result = this.getUser(userId)
  //     .pipe(map((user: IUser | undefined) => user?.movieRatings))
  //     .forEach(
  //       next: rating: IMovieRating
  //     );
  
  return result;
 }
```

Any help for a beginner Angular programmer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go:**

```ts
getUserRatings(userId: number): Observable<IMovieRating[]> {
    return this.getUser(userId)
      .pipe(
        map((user: IUser | undefined) => user?.movieRatings || []),
        catchError(() => []),
      );
  }
```

Use the `map` operator to extract the `movieRatings` property from the user object. The optional chaining `?.` ensures that it won't throw an error if the user object is undefined. If it's undefined, we provide an empty array as a default value.

Add a `catchError` operator to handle potential errors. If there's an error during the Observable stream, it returns an empty array.

This modified method ensures that you always get an array of `IMovieRating` objects or an empty array if the user is not found or if there's an error.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Oh wow, I was so close with that last commented out section!  Thanks for the help, my errors are now gone!

Comment: @SeanSmyth Would greatly appreciate an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are some modifications you need to make to your code.

You may not call `getUserRatings` if your `getUser` is undefined.

You are on the right track but you need to modify your code as follows:

```
getUserRatings(userId: number): Observable<IMovieRating[]>{
  return this.getUser(userId).pipe(map((user) => user?.movieRatings || []));
}
```